# IOS UIButton setBackgroundColor has no effect

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a UIButton that I create in a storyboard and assign to a property in my view controller through an outlet.

I want to make the button be transparent, but the code that I am using to (try to) do this seems to have no effect, specifically in viewDidLoad I call:

```
[self.signUpButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

The button maintains the default background colour acquired from the storyboard definition.

So - my questions are - 1) Why doesn't this work? 2) Can the background colour of a button be defined in the story board?

Cheers,

Owen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an image.

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```

Comment: I've also tried setting the image and background image to be a transparent png, but this does not seem to have any effect either.

Comment: great - yes that's it, so obvious now.